# jQuery: select elements with slice

Tags: javascript, jquery

in a page i've got different divs elements with the same class

```
<div id="masterdiv">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
<div>
```

with a setTimeout i want to take three elements for time do some action with them.

i tried with the slice function:

```
var elements = $("#masterdiv").find('.a');

var t = setInterval(function () {
   var currentElements = elements.slice(points.f, points.l); 
  /* where points.f = 0 and points.l = 3 */
  /* do something with currentElements then increment points.f and points.l +1 */

}, xinterval );
```

But there's a problem, at a certain time my code will reach a .slice(8,10) / .slice(9,11) and a in a selection of 11 divs.

So in these cases (`point.l > elements.length()`) i want select the first divs instead of the exceeded ones:

- In the case of .slice(8,10) i want to select instead of the
  inexistent div '10' the div 0 with the 8,9 divs .
- In the case of .slice(9,11) i want to select instead of the
  inexistent divs '10','11' the div 0,1 with the 9 div.

How can i accomplish this? Can i do it with slice or should i use another function?

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: you could always check if points.ls is >= elements.length

Comment: is your points.l on start really 3? If, so, you will not have .slice(8,10) situation. l is 2, rather? Anyway, your point is clear.

Comment: yhea, @sinisake i've typed wrong the slice rane, no points.l start from 3 so whe have a situation like .slice(8,11) and .slice(9,12).

Comment: why not use for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative, would be to use the pop() and push() array functions like this:

```
var $elements = $("#masterdiv").find('.a');
// Convert to native Array
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.apply($elements);

var t = setInterval(function () {

  elements.slice(points.f,points.l).forEach(function(el){ 

      // do something on the element... 
      $(el).addClass('debug');

   });
  elements.push(elements.shift()); // Re-arrange elements array for loop

}, xinterval );
```

Here's the codepen demo: http://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/mRVzqQ?editors=0010

Answer (score 2):

you can increment your variable like this,

```js
var elements = $("#masterdiv").find('.a');

  /* where points.f = 0 and points.l = 3 */
var t = setInterval(function () {
 var currentElements;
  
  if(points.l > elements.length && points.f<=elements.length){
    tempArr1 = elements.slice(points.f);
    tempVar = points.l % elements.length;
    tempArr2 = elements.slice(0,tempVar);
    currentElements = [...tempArr1,...tempArr2];
    
  }
  else{
   currentElements = elements.slice(points.f, points.l); 
  }
  
  /* do something with currentElements then increment points.f and points.l +1 */  

}, xinterval );
```

I have not covered edge cases,please find yourself ;)